# Given a pretty complex joint PDF of X,Y, what can I derive about them?

Tags: probability, random-variables

this is the kind of questions where from just looking at you realize that the answer might not be straightforward:

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)\begin{cases}
  e^{-y}e^{-xy}y^2 & y>0 ,x\geq0\\    
  0 & else
\end{cases}
$$

And the questions is: **What can you conclude about X,Y?** (Are they independent? $Cov(X,Y)>0$ ? $COV(X,Y)<0$? are they coordinated? etc.

Well, as a newbie, I started by calculating $ f_X(x)$. It didn't work out. It was too complicated and I got stuck. I then turned to $f_Y(y)$ which gave me $f_Y(y) = ye^{-y}$, but I couldn't figure out what to do with that data. 
So I then though that this is probably deeper than just a technically solvable problem, there's probably a concept behind it.

Could you please enlighten me?

Thanks!

Comment: \begin{align}
f_{X,Y}(x,y)&=y^2e^{-(1+x)y}\mathbf1_{y>0,x>0}
\\&=\underbrace{\frac{(1+x)^3}{2}y^2e^{-(1+x)y}\mathbf1_{y>0}}_{f_{Y\mid X=x}(y)}\frac{2}{(1+x)^3}\mathbf1_{x>0}
\end{align}

It is clear that $Y\mid X$ has a Gamma density which depends on $X$, hence $X,Y$ are not independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent iff the joint density is the product of the marginal densities. You have found the density of $Y$. For the density of $X$, note that
$$
f_{X}(x)=\int_0^\infty f(x,y)\, dy=\frac{2}{(x+1)^3}\int_{0}^\infty \frac{(x+1)^3}{2}y^{2}e^{-y(x+1)}\, dy=\frac{2}{(x+1)^3}\quad (x\geq0)
$$ 
where the integral equals one since it is the integral of a [gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) density with shape parameter $3$ and rate parameter $x+1$.

It follows that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.